# Excel VBA: Moving data from sheet to workbook / creating a new workbook per sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move data from one workbook to another workbook in a certain way. The situation is as follows:

I have two workbooks: "`workbook_1`" and a "`workbook_template`"

I need to move data from the sheets of `wb_1` to `wb_template` and save it as new/create a new workbook per sheet. More precisely: the `wb_template` should be saved as a new file for every sheet of `wb_1`.

For example, if `wb_1` has 5 sheets, there should be 5 new `wb_templates` created.

**Defining the range:**

Instead of defining the cells/columns, I need to look for keywords inside of the sheets of wb1 and move/translate it to wb_template. So instead of "blindly" moving values from cell to cell, I would need to look for certain keywords in `wb_1` -> change the wording(translating) of those keywords and then placing them in a certain cell in `wb_template`.

.
.
.

**For this I have two possible scenarios:**

**1.** Looking for a certain term and translating it to the `wb_template`:

> wb_1/sheet 1/"house_1" => move it to wb_template in a certain
>   sheet/cell(wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")) as "house blue"

https://pasteboard.co/HBxorVS.png

.
.
.

**2.** Looking for a certain term and just taking the value which is stored
    in the cell on the right side of it:

> wb_1/sheet 1/"number" | "4" =>  move it to wb_template in a certain
>       sheet/cell (wb_template.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")) as as "4"

https://pasteboard.co/HBxoLaG.png

.
.
.

**Here is a simple overview visual showing what i excactly want to achieve with the macro:**

https://pasteboard.co/HBxq1Dh.png

.
.
.

The code that I use right now for the range is the following:

```
Sub Transferfile(wbTempPath As String, wbTargetPath As String)

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb_template As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetPath)
Set wb_template = Workbooks.Open(wbTempPath)

'/* Definition of the value range  */

wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value

wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value


wb1Name = Left(wb1.Name, InStr(wb1.Name, ".") - 1)
wb_template.SaveAs wb1.Path & "\" & wb1Name & "_New.xlsx"

wb1.Close False
wb_template.Close False

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: What specific coding question are you asking? It's unclear where the problem is. I see you have pasted an example of a procedure above, but you have not highlighted any errors. What is wrong exactly? What have you tried? Why is behaviour different than you expect?

Comment: Right now, the code above only moves data via a fixed value range. What I need is to modify the code, so that the data is moved according to scenario 1 and scenario 2.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking in those scenarios. Perhaps edit your question to expand the code of what you've tried regarding those scenarios, including them as part of your actual sub, and highlighting any errors or unexpected behaviour.